# Display list of branch with their latest tag

Tags: git

Is there a way to list branches (`git branch`) along with the latest tag they have (`git describe`)?

The result I want would be

```
  branch1 (based on V1.1)
* branch2 (based on V1.2)
  branch3 (based on V2)
```

Here version numbers are tags.
And I want to keep the colors and format I set up in my custom `--format`,

For now, my idea was something looking like that:

```
versions=$(git branch --format "%(refname:short)" | xargs git describe --abbrev=0)
git branch --format "$(HEAD) $(refname:short) (based on [[???]])
```

where ??? would be some expansion of `versions` that would be first line on first line, second line on second line, ...

Is this the good approach? What is the good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Run a loop over all branches and inside the loop call `git describe --tags` for every branch.

Run a loop over all branches:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads/
```

Print only short name:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/
```

Create a shell script that calls `git describe` for every branch:

```
git for-each-ref --format='echo %(refname:short) Based on $(git describe --tags %(refname));' refs/heads/
```

And finally evaluate the script:

```
eval `git for-each-ref --format='echo %(refname:short) Based on $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 %(refname));' --shell refs/heads/`
```

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) with examples.

Another approach is to run the loop outside `git for-each-ref`:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/ |
    while read ref; do
        echo "$ref" Based on `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 "$ref"`
    done
```

Comment: Thanks! But apparently the color is not preserved through the echo : with `git for-each-ref --format="%(color:green)%(refname)" refs/heads/` all is green, but with eval `git for-each-ref --format="echo %(color:green)%(refname);" --shell refs/heads/` nothing is green

Comment: @sayanel `git for-each-ref --color=always`

Comment: with `color=always` the text is indeed colored but after the first line it it inproperly escaped and print `bash: $'\E[m': command not found` (with the command ``eval `git for-each-ref --color=always --format='echo %(color:green)%(refname:short) Based on $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 %(refname));' refs/heads/` ``)

Answer (score 0):

> Another approach is to run the loop outside `git for-each-ref`:
>
> ```
> git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/ |
>    while read ref; do
>        echo "$ref" Based on `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 "$ref"`
>    done
> ```

Actually, with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), "[`git branch --list  --format=<format>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/70e5c5ddddadc7f15f64f812ae511eab83ca0040/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L182)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---list))</sup> and friends are taught a new "`%(describe)`" placeholder.

See [commit f5d18f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5d18f8c0ef9cc3e62420268c2e72d1fd46b940c), [commit f46094a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f46094a5e6b80098786b4e1448be032dfbdf3f43) (23 Jul 2023) by [Kousik Sanagavarapu (`five-sh`)](https://github.com/five-sh).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 70e5c5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70e5c5ddddadc7f15f64f812ae511eab83ca0040), 02 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5d18f8c0ef9cc3e62420268c2e72d1fd46b940c): add new "`describe`" atom
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Hariom Verma</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kousik Sanagavarapu</sup>

> Duplicate the logic of `%(describe)` and friends from pretty to ref-filter.
> In the future, this change helps in unifying both the formats as ref-filter will be able to do everything that pretty is doing and we can have a single interface.
>
> The new atom "`describe`" and its friends are equivalent to the existing pretty formats with the same name.

`git for-each-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5d18f8c0ef9cc3e62420268c2e72d1fd46b940c/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L261-L283):

> ### `describe[:options]`
>
> A human-readable name, like [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe);
> empty string for undescribable commits. The `describe` string may
> be followed by a colon and one or more comma-separated options.
>
> - `tags=<bool-value>`
>   Instead of only considering annotated tags, consider
>   lightweight tags as well; see the corresponding option in
>   [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) for details.
> - `abbrev=<number>`
>   Use at least  hexadecimal digits; see the corresponding
>   option in [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) for details.
> - `match=<pattern>`
>   Only consider tags matching the given `glob(7)` pattern,
>   excluding the "refs/tags/" prefix; see the corresponding option
>   in [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) for details.
> - `exclude=<pattern>`
>   Do not consider tags matching the given `glob(7)` pattern,
>   excluding the "`refs/tags/`" prefix; see the corresponding option
>   in [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) for details.

So `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) %(describe)' refs/heads` would be enough.